# How can I plug that in to euler's eq: $e^{\lambda i}= \cos(\lambda) + i\sin(\lambda)$ to find an eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume that $U$ is a subspace of the space of infinitely differentiable (complex valued) functions of real numbers that is spanned by $f_1=e^t \cos(t)$ and $f_2=e^t \sin(t)$.

What is the eigenvalue and eigenvector for $T$ on $U$? Given:

$T(f)=\frac {df}{dt}$

$T\in \mathcal L \left({U}\right)$

I already answered this question and got that the D.E has solution: $e^{t}\cos t,e^{t}\sin t$ and $\lambda = 2+2i$ and $\lambda = 2-2i$.

Now the problem is that I have a complex number. How can I plug that in to euler's eq: $e^{\lambda i}= \cos(\lambda) + i\sin(\lambda)$ to find an eigenvector in $V$?

Comment: can't seem to follow that...they lose me when they multiply by the conjugate

Comment: yes the matrix is:

row 1:  (1- $\lambda$)      1

row 2:  -1     (1-$\lambda$)

Sorry dont know how to do matrix in latex

Comment: i edited my post

Comment: yes @moo thats right

Answer (score 1):

We are given the matrix:

$$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 1 \\
 -1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

The eigenvalues are given by $|A - \lambda I| = 0 \implies \lambda_{1, 2} = 1~\pm ~ i$.

To find the eigenvectors, we want to solve $[A- \lambda_i I]v_i = 0$. For $\lambda_1 = 1 + i$, we have:

$$[A- \lambda_1 I]v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
 1-(1 + i) & 1 \\
 -1 & 1-(1+i) \\
\end{bmatrix}v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
 -i & 1 \\
 -1 & -i \\
\end{bmatrix}v_1 = 0$$

If we take $i \times R1 + R2 \rightarrow R2$, we get:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
 -i & 1 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}v_1 = 0$$

Now, we can choose the eigenvector:

$$v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
 -i \\ 1 \\\end{bmatrix}$$

Since the eigenvalues are complex conjugate, so too are the eigenvectors, so you already know $v_2$

Notice how these eigenvalues lead to the solutions you show as $e^t \cos t, e^t \sin t$, if not, follow the examples in these [*notes*](http://www.math.vt.edu/people/afkhamis/class_home/notes/F08W11b.pdf).